# asp.net ashx request 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ashx

I am using an ashx request handler to retrieve images and my breakpoint in the ashx file isn't being hit. When I use firebug I can see that the request is returning a 404 which makes me think that I need to configure some setting so that ashx file can be found.

I am using visual studio 2008 and .net 3.5.

**ASHX file**

```
namespace hybrid.content.Handlers
{
 public class DB_Images : IHttpHandler
 {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 image_id;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            image_id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = GetImageFromDatabase(image_id);
        if (strm != null)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
            //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
    }

    public Stream GetImageFromDatabase(int image_id)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        //connstr.InitialCatalog = "dummy";
        //connstr.UserID = "sa";
        //connstr.Password = "password";
        //connstr.DataSource = "source";
        connstr.InitialCatalog = "smsdb";
        connstr.UserID = "user";
        connstr.Password = "password";
        connstr.DataSource = "10.31.4.79";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        //            cmd.CommandText = "select image from cis_images where image_id = @p_image_id";
        cmd.CommandText = "select image from test_images where image_id = @p_image_id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_image_id", image_id);
        conn.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Page click event**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/DB_Images.ashx?id=" + TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

**ashx html**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="DB_Images.ashx.cs" Class="hybrid.content.Handlers.DB_Images" %>
```

There isn't any html apart from that reference.

Is there something that I am missing to get this to work?

Comment: Could you paste what you have on the "html" view of the handler? (the content of the ashx file)

Comment: Is IIS setup to serve handlers?

Comment: @TheSavage IIS is setup to serve handlers.

Comment: What happens if you navigate the httphandler on your browser?

Comment: @Claudio Redi I get a server error in '/' application. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /DB_Images.ashx


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Comment: is the ASHX being properly copied into your deployment location?

Comment: The ASHX file is in the same folder as the page. Unless your referring to something else?

Comment: @nickgowdy are you using asp.net's development server, or IIS? If IIS, what version? What happens if you use the ASP.Net development server?

Comment: When I debug it says I am using ASP.Net development server, but I am not sure which version. I should also mention that the code I am using works in visual studio 2010 but our systems use 2008. Thats why I am interested in a difference between the two which would cause the code not to work.

Comment: Its ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Generic Handlers in ASP.NET, there are a few things to check on.

1.) Make sure you have set the "32 bit application" flag in your application pool to 32 bit if it really is 32 bit.  The default is "False".

2.) Turn the application pool from Integrated to Classic

3.) Change the .NET version in your application pool appropriately.  In your case, use v2, since 3.5 uses version 2.  .NET 4.0 uses .NET 4.0.

4.) Make sure ASP.NET is registered.  Run everything in the code blocks.

C:\>`cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\{version}`
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64{version}>`aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

5.) Choose the "ISAPI & CGI Restrictions" after right clicking the server name (not the site name) in IIS Manager, and right click the correct "ASP.NET {version}" line and chose "Allow".

6.) Make sure you have your Handler Mappings (for *.ashx) turned on (aka "Enabled") at the server level, or site level or explicitly in the web.config.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on step #6? I have registered my specific ASHX in web.config but am not sure what you mean by `*.ashx`

Comment: I wrote "Allowed".  I should have written "Enabled".  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Tim, I'm coming back to this for my own purposes, again.  #4 and #5 go together.  #6 is totally different.  Sorry I disclosed the wrong information to you in my last comment.  #4 and #5 allow the ashx files to be installed (and turned on/allowed) by ASP.NET for the specific .NET version (by default only v2.* is in IIS).  Those are ISAPI filters.  #6 (Handler Mappings) allow ASP.NET to interpret when to apply a certain mappings (ashx, other, etc..) for different verbs (GET, POST, etc..) and for defined classes (handlers) in your application or server.

Comment: I also flip flopped the order of #4 and #5 because #4 is the install, and #5 is turning them on.  By default, if you turn on IIS in Windows, v2.* filters will be in that list (for #5), and the v4.* will be set to "Not Allowed".  Change those v4.* lines to "Allowed"

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the ashx file marked as a None content type instead of as Content, i.e. the *Properties -> Build Action* for it should have been **Content**, which mean that the ashx file wasn't included when Publishing the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the url. `~/` means your root directory .

```
 Use ResolveClientUrl("yourPathHere") or  ResolveUrl("yourPathHere").
```

To get details about this error check the image's source and copy and paste it in the address bar. A yellow page consisting of the details will popup.

I think the only problem is the url.